# joomla 3x insert a string into sql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, joomla, insert

I'm currently running a joomla 3x portal and need to insert a string into my MySQL database, but have had no success so far (sadly, I'm not a programmer).

So I added a new field into my users table called "ok1" and just want to insert a string into it (actually a hyperlink) and overwrite it every time with the current one on the page that executed the code last.

This is the code I used, but it always "blows" my portal...

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$columns = "ok1"; 
$values = "my hyperlink";

$query
    ->insert($db->quoteName('#__users'))
    ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
    ->values($db->quoteName($values));

$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();
```

Hopefully somebody can help me out with this one, thanks in advance.

Second attempt:

```
$content ="test"
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
Update `x__users` SET `ok1`=$content WHERE `user` = $user->id;
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->execute();
```

Comment: Are you just trying to store a single value? Or create a new database entry every time?

Comment: Please try asking your question over at [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Among other things values are not names and should just have `quote` not `quoteName`.   Also it's really a rather odd query. There is no column called ok1 in the user table.

Comment: @ Martyn Shutt: I want to just replace the old value with the new one. The goal ist to show the user which page he last visited

Comment: @Elin: that was the best I could come up with. I actually added the field "ok1" in the user-table

Comment: @Lodder: thank you I will try this too!

Comment: So at minimum you need a WHERE  to indicate what row to update. Also don't you probably need update not insert?

Comment: @Elin: sounds right -  The update-query works in mysql-admin, but still habe troubles to implement it into joomla -> see main topic under "Second Attempt"

Comment: That's not in the query. you need to replace `$query->insert` with `$query->update` and add a `query->where` and also add `set->` .

Comment: @Elin: Thanks for your answers, but I don't get it. Please provide a code snipped so I can grasp it! Thanks in advanced

Comment: What is it that you think the third line is going to do? It has nothing to do with $query. You can't just stick a link of random text in the middle of your code. Just use the same idea you had originally but as I said use update and add the where etc.  There are a ton of examples of update queries in the Joomla code base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it - thanks to all for help:

For Joomla 3.x

Update a column/field in MySQL-Database via php
Display column/field from a MySQL-Database via php

To get the Data into the Database use following Code:

```
// $columns represent the name of the column/filed in the table
// $values represent the value the column/filed should be updated with
$columns = "ok1"; 
$values = "my hyperlink";

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query
    ->update($db->quoteName('#__users')) //the name of the table
    ->set($db->quoteName($columns) . ' = ' . $db->quote($values)) 
    ->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' = ' . $user->id) //the current user ID to match the column "id" 
;

$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();
```

To get the Data out of the Database use following Code:

```
$query= "SELECT `ok1` FROM `#__users` WHERE `id` = $user->id"; 
$database->setQuery($query);
$ok1_link= $database->loadResult();
```

*I use und recommend a great extension called [Sourcerer](https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer#description) to place the code direct into an article - works flawlessly basic version is for free and support is also top!!*

Answer (score 0):

What you want is something like this

```
$columns = "ok1"; 
$values = "my hyperlink";

$query
    ->update($db->quoteName('#__users'))

    ->set($db->quoteName($columns) = $db->quote($values))
    ->where($db-quoteName('user') = $user->id)
;

$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();
```

That is to say you want to update a record not insert a new one, and you want it to be the specific record indicated by the where clause. Also use the correct quote for values (since they are not names).

Comment: Thanks a lot Elin!! I'm currently on the run and and justed tested it with copy paste it into my site and my site blanked out -> white. But I currently have no access to the logfiles. I will report when I have - As I said bevor thanks for your help1

Comment: Ok I now checked the error-logs but there I just found an entry called "referer" followed by the url of the php containing site - so still a blank white page

Comment: Turn error reporting to development (in global configuration).  Also you can add `echo $query->dump(): `   to see the generated query.   Okay I got rid of some extra lines.

Comment: Thanks for your countinuing help. I got following output: "Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in ... path ... on line 8" which would be in this case "->set($db->quoteName($columns) = $db->quote($values))"